# The Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation (NLSE)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, laser, non-linear-optics, non-linear-schroedinger

I am trying to show that the NLSE:

$$\frac{\partial A(z,T)}{\partial z} = -i \frac{\beta_2}{2} \frac{\partial^2A}{\partial T^2} + i \gamma |A|^2 A$$

may be cast in the form:

$$\frac{\partial U(z,\tau)}{\partial z} = -i \frac{sign \beta_2}{2} \frac{1}{L_D} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \tau^2} + i \frac{1}{L_{NL}} |U|^2 U$$

by normalizing with: $\tau = \frac{T}{T_0}, \ \ A(z,T) = \sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau).$

**Attempt:**

I introduced the normalized amplitude $U$ and also the expression for $\tau$ into the first equation above:

$$\frac{\partial (\sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau))}{\partial z} = -i \frac{\beta_2}{2} \frac{\partial^2(\sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau))}{\partial (\tau T_0)^2} + i \gamma |(\sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau))|^2 (\sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau))$$

We know that the dispersion length is given by $L_D = \frac{T_0^2}{|\beta_2|}$ and the the nonlinear length is $L_{NL} = \frac{1}{\gamma P_0}.$ So the expression becomes:

$$\frac{\partial (\sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau))}{\partial z} = -i \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{L_D} \frac{\partial^2(\sqrt{P_0} U(z, \tau))}{\partial \tau^2} + i \frac{1}{L_{NL}} \sqrt{P_0} P_0 U^2 U$$

So, what can I do about the extra $\sqrt{P_0}$'s and the extra $P_0$?

Is my derivation correct so far? And how do we get the "$sign \ \beta_2$" part? That is either $\pm 1$ (sign of the GVD parameter).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.